# How to find how many wins until next portrait?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

How do I figure out how many wins of what race you need until next portrait?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I correctly understood, you should:

1. right click o your icon in the game (in the top right corner)
2. click 'select portrait'
3. hover mouse onto required portrait, you will know type of the game ("Team", "Solo", etc.), race (Terran, Random, etc.), how many games you need to win to get the portrait.

After that go to achievements - quick match - into required game type and find required achievement. It will:
- list all portraits per achievement
- display amount of matches you won
- amount matches left to win to get achievement.

Hope that helps.